# PackageFatJar task from Groovy to Groovy DSL

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, groovy, groovydsl

I have a gradle task written in Groovy

```
task packageFatJar(type: Jar) {
    group 'build'
    description 'package fat jar for migrations app with all dependencies'
    baseName = 'app-fat'
    zip64 = true
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

I want to change it to Groovy DSL

I have this code ready:

```
tasks.create<Jar>("packageFatJar") {
    group = "build"
    description = "package fat jar for group call common app with all dependencies"
    baseName = "app-fat"
    isZip64 = true

}
```

But, I don't know how to convert this part:

```
from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
with jar
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Is using the most excellent Shadow plugin out of the question? https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.plugin-shadow